# Azure functions: Can I implement my architecture and how do I minimize cost?

Tags: python, azure

I am interested in implementing a compute service for an application im working on in the cloud. The idea is there are 3 modules in the service. A compute manager that receives requests (with input data), triggers azure function computes (the computes are the 2nd 'module'). Both modules share same blob storage for the scripts to be run and the input / output data (json) for the compute.

I'm wanting to draw up a basic diagram but need to understand a few things first. Is the thing I described above possible, or must azure functions have their own separate storage. Can azure functions have concurrent executions of same script with different data.

I'm new to Azure so what I've been learning about Azure functions hasn't yet answered my questions. I'm also unsure how to minimise cost. The functions wont run often.

I hope someone could shed some light on this for me :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, Azure function itself has many kinds of triggers. For example: HTTP trigger, Storage trigger, or Service Bus trigger.

So, I think you can use it without your computer manager if there is one inbuilt trigger meets your requirements.

At the same time, all functions can share same storage account. You just need to use the correct storage account connection string.

And, at the end, as your function will not run often, I suggest you use [azure function consumption plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan). When you're using the Consumption plan, instances of the Azure Functions host are dynamically added and removed based on the number of incoming events.